# How do I deploy my xcode webplugin for safari?

Tags: xcode, deployment, safari

I have a c project built into a .webplugin that works when I install it manually (i.e. copy it to the Library/Internet Plug-Ins folder) but how do I get this to users who visit the web site most expediently?  From my investigation it sounds like one must build an installer that a user must download (as with flash, quicktime).
-Is there any way for it to install via the browser (Safari) as Activex controls do in IE?
-If I must build an installer, how would I begin? 
-If I must use an installer, is there any way to detect if the plugin is already installed so that I can prompt the user accordingly?

Thanks very, very much for your time. This has been such a thorn in my side!

Answer (score 0):

> Is there any way for it to install via the browser (Safari) as Activex controls do in IE?

No. IE no longer supports this behavior for ActiveX anyway, as allowing any web site to install software on a user's computer is a massive security vulnerability.

Note in general that requiring an Internet Plugin to view your site will end up turning away a lot of viewers. Unless your web application has some really unusual needs, I'd question whether this is necessary -- JavaScript is capable of some really impressive things nowadays.

> If I must build an installer, how would I begin?

Start here: [PackageMaker User Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/PackageMakerUserGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html) (Mac OS X Developer Library)

> If I must use an installer, is there any way to detect if the plugin is already installed so that I can prompt the user accordingly?

If you build an installer using PackageMaker, I believe the installer will detect this situation automatically.